# Angular2 countdown display onClick Event for a second for another function needs time to process its code

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have my original code in angular1 in which there are `two functions`: `start()` and `startFilling()`. `start()` is called a button `click`. `startFiling() needs 10 seconds to process` once the user clicks Start button that fires start(). A `counter` (which I have bound to template)  which goes in `desc mode from 10 till 0` so that `user` gets feedback of how much time is `left to process his request`.

Template:

```
<div align="center" ng-if="counter">
    <h5>Countdown  {{counter}}</h5>
</div>
<button class="button button-dark start-button" ng-click="start()" ng-disabled="disableStart">Start</button>
```

Controller:

```
counter=10;
$scope.start = function(){
  ...
  ...

  $timeout($scope.startFilling, 10000) <= call startFilling() after 10 seconds 
  $scope.onTimeout = function(){
    $scope.counter--;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

    if($scope.counter==0){
     $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
     $scope.counter=0
    }
  }

  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000); <= calling onTimeout() at each second to decrease the counter
}

$scope.startFilling = function(){
  console.log("startFilling()")
}
```

**How can I achieve this in Angular2?**

So far I have like this:

```
counter=10
timeoutId: any;

start(){
 ...
 ...

    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.startFilling()
                }, 10000)

    var onTimeout: ()=> {

    }

    var newTimeoutId= setTimeout(()=>{onTimeout()},1000);

}

startFilling(){

   console.log("startFilling()")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start** is called a button click

```
public counter: number;
public timer: any;

constructor() {}   

start() {
    this.counter = 10;
     window.clearInterval(this.timer);
     this.timer = setInterval(() => {
       this.counter--;
       if(this.counter === 0) {
            window.clearInterval(this.timer);

            /*After counter value is 0 means 10000 is completed */
            this.startFilling();
          }
     }, 1000);
}

startFilling() {
   console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: And how about decreasing the counter?

Comment: Okay let me check this

Comment: It somehow doesn't decrease the counter from 10 till 0 each second after start() is fired, instead after 10 seconds counter is displayed on the screen as 9 from 10

Comment: After each start  click you want to decrease to 10-0 or automatically onces start is clicked you want to decrease 10-0

Comment: so once start() is fired startFilling() is called after 10 seconds, that much is correct in your code. But during these 10 seconds the user should see the counter going down like 10..9..8....0

Comment: @Nitish Use the edited code as the before code can fail in case for the second difference

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 has rxjs Support. 
You use [Observable.timer](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md) for it.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'Ticks (every second) : {{ticks}}'
})
export class AppComponent {
  ticks =0;
  ngOnInit(){
    let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
    timer.subscribe(t=>this.ticks = t);
  }
}
```

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Cx1jJhUynRbw3j4xRPE?p=preview)